# Intercepting child method calls using Unity

Tags: unity-container, enterprise-library, aop, unity-interception

Using PIAB / Unity, is it possible to intercept "child" method calls ?

e.g. the class has three methods ...

```
DoSomething(), DoFirst(), DoSecond()
```

The DoSomething() method calls DoFirst() which in turn calls DoSecond()

I can get interception of DoSomething, but I can't get anything for DoFirst and DoSecond. I've tried various of the Policy Injection rules ... Type Matching, Tag Attribute, Method Signature ... but nothing works. But I can intercept each method if I call them directly

So basic question ... can you even do this ?

And if so, how !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that I need to use the VirtualMethodInterceptor rather than the TransparentProxy or Interception interceptors